# SQL Query Help, filtering by client ID

Tags: sql

```
SELECT
    tblArtworkTemplates.ID,
    tblArtworkTemplates.userID as creatorID,
    tblArtworkTemplates.dateCreated,
    tblSpecifications.TxtPagination, 
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeW AS width,
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeL AS length,
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeUOM AS uom,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1
        FROM tblArtworkUploads
        WHERE (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS uploadCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS talks
        FROM tblArtworkTemplateMessages
        WHERE (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS talkCount,
    tblUsers.id AS editUserID,
    tblUsers.userName,
    CAST((CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(n, tblArtworkTemplates.lastEditPing, getDate()) < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS 'IsInLast5Mins'
FROM
    tblUsers RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    tblArtworkTemplates INNER JOIN
    tblSpecifications
        ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id
        ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
WHERE
    (tblArtworkTemplates.userID = @userID)
```

This works fine for passing in the user ID to filter on.  However, each user in tblUsers has a clientID.  I want to instead of filtering by user ID, filter by client ID.

So I pass in where client ID = 21, and it returns a list of all the records where the user who created it has the client ID of 21.

I know this is an incredibly boring question and mind numbing but any help is hugely appreciated.

**Edit: Table Structure**

```
tblArtworkTemplates:
  - ID
  - userID (who created it)

tblUsers
  - ID
  - clientID
```

So instead of filtering on userID which is easy because that is stored in tblArtworkTemplates, I want to filter on client ID.  So if I pass in client ID 21, it gets all artwork template records where the userID has that client ID.

Comment: Can you provide the structure of the different tables?

Comment: @Oded thanks, I have above, I don't think you need to know any more?  The tblSpecification properties are just associated with template Id so aren't really important.

Comment: Ok lol, I just did where tblusers.clientid = 21 and it worked

Comment: ^ no it didn't work :( Only shows 12 records.  There are over 200 records where user id = 70, and user 70 has a client id of 21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    tblArtworkTemplates.ID,
    tblArtworkTemplates.userID as creatorID,
    tblArtworkTemplates.dateCreated,
    tblSpecifications.TxtPagination, 
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeW AS width,
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeL AS length,
    tblSpecifications.FlatSizeUOM AS uom,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS Expr1
        FROM tblArtworkUploads
        WHERE (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS uploadCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(1) AS talks
        FROM tblArtworkTemplateMessages
        WHERE (templateID = tblArtworkTemplates.ID)) AS talkCount,
    tblUsers.id AS editUserID,
    tblUsers.userName,
    CAST((CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(n, tblArtworkTemplates.lastEditPing, getDate()) < 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS bit) AS 'IsInLast5Mins'
FROM
    tblUsers RIGHT OUTER JOIN
    tblArtworkTemplates INNER JOIN
    tblSpecifications
        ON tblArtworkTemplates.specID = tblSpecifications.id
        ON tblUsers.id = tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID
WHERE
    (tblArtworkTemplates.creatorID IN (Select ID From tblUsers 
     Where clientID = @clientID)
```

It seemed from your query that `tblArtworkTemplates.editPingUserID` was `tblUsers.id`

Comment: This only returns 12 rows unfortunatly, there are 200 records with the creatorID being 70, and user 70's client id is 21

Comment: @Tom Gullen could you expand your table structure then as I see no other relationship between the records.

Comment: It does work now sorry!  In the where, we are filtering on creatorID, not editPingUserID, thanks very much for your answer!